# Is there a way to put comments in an rsync --files-from file?

Tags: rsync

I have a file that rsync uses as --files-from:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

I want to be able to put comments above each dir entry like that:

```
# my dir1 comment
dir1

#dir2 comment
dir2

#yet another comment
dir3
```

but rsync complains "No such file or directory"

So far I have tried #,//,--,,SPACE

Is there a way to comment out/disable entries?

Comment: I am not aware of any commenting mechanism for the `files-from` file.

Answer (score 23):

According to the `man` page on `rsync:`

> "...Blank lines in FILE and lines starting with  ’;’  or  ’#’ are  ignored..."

I just ran a quick test and indeed `#` and `;` lines are ignored.

Comment: I can't seconds the `;` but the `#` (looking [here](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/teaching/2501ICT/cgi-bin/man.cgi?rsync+1), searching ‚when rules are...‘). → So arguably `#` is a bit safer...

Comment: Not in this rSync man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync , neither in this other: https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html. Could you please refer yours?

Comment: Your page does indeed show that lines starting with # are comments: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync  indicates "...When rules are being read from a file, empty lines are ignored, as are comment lines that start with a lq#rq.  ..."  (lq and rq are notation for left quote and right quote...I don't know why that Web page renders quotes as these abbreviations).  Regardless, # in an rsync exclude file are comments.  Perhaps the other man page you reference is simply old.  You can review the rsync log history here: https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=log

Comment: The best thing to do is to look at the man page on the platform where you are developing to determine the version of rsync you are using; you can search the man page for how comments are handled by that version of rsync.

Answer (score 10):

Do a `grep -v '^#' file > /tmp/filetmp` and then launch your rsync on `/tmp/filetmp`

Depending on your shell, you may be able to avoid the temporary file (this is valid in Bash):

```
rsync --files-from <(grep -v '^#' file) …
```

The weird-looking `<( … )` syntax is what Bash calls [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

Comment: I added the pattern to your grep for you—I assume this is what you meant... I'm going to add in a bash trick as well, feel free to revert one or both edits if you disagree.

Comment: You may use `--files-from=-` to have `rsync` read the list from standard input.

Answer (score -1):

state for now (rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31): all lines starting from `#` or `;` are ignored even `man` have no information about that (my case was different, I wanted to copy a file named `;_char` and was surprised that wasn't even using --from0 option - after changing line to `./;_char` it started to work). Seems that the same parsing function is used as for options `--include-from` or `--exclude-from`
For these two options `man` page mention:

`Blank lines  in  the file and lines starting with ’;’ or ’#’ are ignored`